# Backbone.js - Using a real-time (socket.io) data source as a dynamic model

Tags: backbone.js, socket.io

I have zero experience with Backbone.js currently, and before I start having a good look, I wonder if anybody could advise if it is a good fit for my use case.

I have a dashboard where I will present multiple real-time graphs, with the data source being provided a socket.io.

I would like to use the same data source on multiple pages of the dashboard.

Would backbones's models be a good fit here i.e. setup a model that uses the socket.io data source, and then makes it available to all views?

Basically whenever socket.on is called, i need an object in each of the views to be updated.

Is this possible?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Best regards, Ben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that's possible. There's a library for Backbone that replaces the Backbone.sync method with an implementation that works over Socket.IO:

https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind